# How are the Stirling-based bounds for the factorial function proven?

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, factorial

According to (26) on [wolfram mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html), one has

$$\sqrt{2\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.04 in}\pi} \cdot n^{n+(1/2)} \cdot \operatorname{exp}((-n)\hspace{-0.02 in}+\hspace{-0.02 in}(1/((12\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.04 in}n)\hspace{-0.02 in}+\hspace{-0.02 in}1)) \;\; < \;\; n!$$ and $$n! \;\; < \;\; \sqrt{2\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.04 in}\pi} \cdot n^{n+(1/2)} \cdot \operatorname{exp}((-n)\hspace{-0.02 in}+\hspace{-0.02 in}(1/(12\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.04 in}n)))$$

.
However, I cannot find that page's Robbins reference anywhere, that page's link for the Feller reference points to amazon.com, and [the only other thing from Feller that I could find on this topic](http://stevereads.com/papers_to_read/direct_proof_of_stirlings_formula.pdf) just cites to Robbins for the bound. $\:$ How are the above two inequalities proven?

Comment: There must be a thousand proofs of Stirling's formula around. Try typing "Stirling's formula" into the web to see what else comes up.

Comment: I just did that. $\:$ I see the wikipedia article, the article I linked to, a proof of the approximation, something that could be combined with Stirling's formula to prove a _non-strict version_ of the _upper_ bound I'm asking about, a physics reference that does nothing like proving it,  another proof of the approximation, two citations to the link I gave in my OP, a page that states very weak bounds and proves the approximation, and two more proofs of the approximation. $\:$ In summary, although there are lots of "proofs of Stirling's formula around", those don't help me. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Robbins' paper is available: https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~marin/une_autre_crypto/articles_et_extraits_livres/Robbin_H.-A_remark_on_Stirling%5C%27s_Formula.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Here we closely follow the proof of H. Robbins presented in *[A Remark on Stirling's Formula](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2308012)*. Some intermediate steps were added to ease reading.

> The following is valid for positive integers $n$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{e^{\frac{1}{12n+1}}<\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}<e^{\frac{1}{12n}}}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

The next partition of $\log(n!)$ is geometrically motivated.

> We obtain 
>   \begin{align*}
> \log(n!)&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log(k+1)\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\int_{k}^{k+1}\log x\,dx+\frac{1}{2}\left(\log(k+1)-\log k\right)-\varepsilon_k\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=\int_{1}^n\log x\,dx+\frac{1}{2}\log n-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\varepsilon_k\\
> &=\big.\left(x\log x-x\right)\big|_{1}^{n}+\frac{1}{2}\log n-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\varepsilon_k\\
> &=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log n-n+1-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\varepsilon_k\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

In the next section we derive a series representation of the error term $\varepsilon_k$ based upon
\begin{align*}
\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=2\left(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+\cdots\right)\qquad\qquad |x|<1
\end{align*}

> We obtain from (2) a representation of the error term $\varepsilon_k$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \varepsilon_k&=\int_{k}^{k+1}\log x\,dx-\frac{1}{2}\log(k+1)-\frac{1}{2}\log k\\
> &=\big.\left(x\log x-x\right)\big|_{k}^{k+1}-\frac{1}{2}\log(k+1)-\frac{1}{2}\log k\\
> &=(k+1)\log(k+1)-(k+1)-k\log k+k-\frac{1}{2}\log(k+1)-\frac{1}{2}\log k\\
> &=\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log(k+1)-\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log k-1\\
> &=\frac{2k+1}{2}\log \frac{k+1}{k}-1\\
> &=\frac{2k+1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+\frac{1}{2k+1}}{1-\frac{1}{2k+1}}\right)-1\\
> &=(2k+1)\left(\frac{1}{2k+1}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{(2k+1)^3}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{(2k+1)^5}+\cdots\right)-1\\
> &=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{(2k+1)^4}+\frac{1}{7}\cdot\frac{1}{(2k+1)^6}+\cdots\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

We derive from (4) the inequalities

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\varepsilon_k}&<\frac{1}{3(2k+1)^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(2k+1)^4}+\cdots\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{3(2k+1)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{12}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)}\tag{5}\\
> \\
> \color{blue}{\varepsilon_k}&>\frac{1}{3(2k+1)^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{3(2k+1)^2}+\frac{1}{\left(3(2k+1)^2\right)^2}+\cdots\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{3(2k+1)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3(2k+1)^2}}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{>\frac{1}{12}\left(\frac{1}{k+\frac{1}{12}}-\frac{1}{k+1+\frac{1}{12}}\right)}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

We now define 
\begin{align*}
B=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \varepsilon_k\qquad\qquad r_n=\sum_{k=n}^\infty \varepsilon_k
\end{align*}
and we see from (5) and (6)
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{12}<B<\frac{1}{13}\tag{7}
\end{align*}

> We can write $\log (n!)$ in the form (3) as
>   \begin{align*}
> \log(n!)=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log n-n+1-B+r_n
> \end{align*}
>   setting $C=e^{1-B}$ we have
>   \begin{align*}
> n!=C\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\cdot e^{-r_n}
> \end{align*}
>   From (5) and (6) we conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{12n+1}<r_n<\frac{1}{12n}}
> \end{align*}
>   and  the claim follows.

From (7) we see that
\begin{align*}
e^{\frac{11}{12}}<C<e^{\frac{12}{13}}
\end{align*}
and   by usual methods it can be shown that $C=\sqrt{2\pi}$.

> **Hint:** The derivation of the double inequality (1) as well as that of  $C=\sqrt{2\pi}$ can also be found in section 1.1 to 1.3 of *[Asymptopia](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1470409046)* by Joel Spencer.