# A combinatoric sum involving the inverse of a square root.

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is there a way to compute, or at least to give a *good* bound to, the following:
\begin{align*}
I_n&:=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\sum_{k=0}^{2j}\binom{2j}{k}\binom{n}{2j-k}^{-1/2}[2j-k\leq n].
\end{align*}
Above $[\cdot]$ denotes the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).
Putting aside silly inequalites (like replacing the inverse square root term with 1 to get $I_n\leq 5^n$), I do not see anything very smart to try, and I did not find something useful elsewhere.

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: @abiessu There is no algebraic background actually, it comes from analysis. To wit, the troublesome square root term is the result of an inequality while the other terms and sums are obtained by expanding the $n$-th and $2j$-th derivatives of products. Feel it won't help unfortunately...

Comment: What do you do when $2j-k> n$ ?

Comment: @Gribouillis Thank you very much for your comment, I omitted something important in the summation!

Comment: Given that the main problem with getting a closed form is the inverse square root binomial, I would look at this paper, which outlines different approximations of the binomial coefficient: http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/shagnik/notes/binomials.pdf.

Comment: @MarcusLuebke Thank you for your feedback, but I am interested in finite $n$ so that such asymptotics are not useable here!

Comment: I would recommend using either the (n/k)^k <= n choose k <= (en/k)^k bounds or the stirling approximation bounds, found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960335/how-are-the-stirling-based-bounds-for-the-factorial-function-proven/2812952

Comment: I think the problem is easier to parse if instead of the Iverson bracket we change the inner summation to begin at lower limit $k = 2j - n$.  Also if we are trying to get a good bound on the inner summation, in terms of $j$ (from the outer summation index) and $n$ (from the problem formulation), we could rewrite the inner summation in terms of $m = 2j$.